# Ruby - how to get and loop through all the values in an object returned from the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this line:

```
@users = database['users'].find(:all).limit(10)
```

it returns this object:

```
<Mongo::Cursor:0x8759a858 namespace='app-development.users' @selector=:all @cursor_id=>
```

and what I thought was that it has a collection of the 10 users it got from the database. Is that correct? I tried iterating through it like this:

```
   @users.each {
        |info|
      logger.debug ".....................single user: " + info.inspect
    }
```

but I got this error:

```
BSON::InvalidDocument (BSON.serialize takes a Hash but got a Symbol):
```

Help much appreciarted!

Comment: is there a longer stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not framiliar with mongo but try this:

```
@users.each do |info|
   logger.debug ".....................single user: #{info.inspect}"
end
```

The #{} allows you to evaluate ruby code within a double quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the litteral result try appending `to_a` to the query. This should give you an array with ten items in it.

```
@users = database['users'].find(:all).limit(10).to_a
```